# How to compare turnover rates across three facilities over a period of 5 years?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures, spss

I need to compare the turnover rates between 3 facilities (turnover calculated as number of voluntary & involuntary terminations divided by the average number of staff multiplied by 100).  In particular, I'm interested in whether one of these facilities demonstrates a lower turnover rate than the other two over a time period of 5 years.
I have average turnover rates for 5 years (2014-2018) for each of these facilities.  I'm guessing a repeated measures would do the trick, but I'm struggling with how to set the dataset up properly and executing the GLM procedure.

I should say that I'm not so much interested in whether there were differences between these facilities in each particular year, but whether there were differences across the entire 5 year time period.

I'm working with SPSS 24.

[image: Data Set: Turnover by facility by year]

Comment: Welcome to the site! I am confused about your dataset and the model you are trying to fit. To me it sounds like you only have 3 observations (the 3 average turnover rates). Can you show which commands you have tried and print an example dataset?

Comment: My apologies, I thought I had attached an image of the dataset (this is now attached).  For each year I have the turnover rate (number of employees terminated/average number of employees x 100).  I would like to know if the variation between facilities (x vs y & z in particular) is more substantial than within facility variation.  That is, Is there reason to believe that x has a significantly lower turnover rate than the other facilities.